# change the width of a drop down parameter box? SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

is there a way within SSRS 2008 R2 to widen the drop down box on a parameter?  The value that I have in the "label" field for my parameter is a concatenation of the customer's name and the city the customer is in -- but the drop down isn't wide enough (and there are no scroll bars) to show all the information, it's just cutting it off :(

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ok, Once I deployed it to the web server, the horizontal scroll bars are there :)  But is there still anyway to make the DD larger so the entire line can be viewed at one time (w/o scrolling)?